# Proof that higher genus surface admits a metric of negative Ricci scalar everywhere

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, differential-geometry

In the Green, Schwarz and Witten Superstring Theory textbook, the paragraph below equation 3.3.15 says,

> For genus greater than one, it can be shown that the surface admits a metric of everywhere negative scalar curvature.

This statement is essential in the proof that $C_g$ for $g>1$ is always zero, but I cannot prove that. Could you point out how to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This result follows from i) [Uniformization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Classification_of_Riemann_surfaces) and ii) [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) in 2d.

According to the statement of uniformization theorem from this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#Classification_of_Riemann_surfaces) :

> every connected Riemann surface X admits a unique complete 2-dimensional real Riemann metric with constant curvature −1, 0 or 1 inducing the same conformal structure

On the other hand, according to [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), integral of the scalar curvature on a 2d surface is a positive multiple of the Euler characteristic ($\chi=2-2g$). Since the Euler characteristic is negative for $g>1$ so from the uniformization theorem it follows that -

> any Riemann surface with genus $g>1$ admits a unique complete 2-dimensional real Riemann metric with constant curvature −1 inducing the same conformal structure

---

Note : I am not aware of any good reference where uniformization thereom is proved in the form stated above. However, I hope you can find a proof in some of the references mentioned in the corresponding wiki article.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that's the answer. To add some materials here: 
For the proof of Uniformization theorem, see

[Uniformization of Riemann Surfaces](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/chan/fulldraft7.pdf) .
 


For further reading, see

GTM 71, Riemann Surfaces, Chpter IV

Answer (score 2):

Why not use explicit construction for such a surface?

From [The Manifold Atlas](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hyperbolic_Surfaces):

> Any hyperbolic metric on a closed, orientable surface $S_g$ of genus $g\ge 2$ is obtained by the following 
>   construction: choose a geodesic $4g$-gon in the hyperbolic plane ${\Bbb H}^2$ with area $4(g-1)\pi$. (This implies that the sum of interior angles is $2\pi$.) Then choose orientation-preserving isometries $I_1,J_1,\ldots,I_g,J_g$ which realise the gluing pattern of $S_g$: for $j=1,\ldots,g$ we require that $I_j$ maps $a_j$ to $\overline{a}_j$, $J_j$ maps $b_j$ to $\overline{b}_j$. Let $\Gamma\subset Isom^+\left({\Bbb H}^2\right)$ be the subgroup generated by $I_1,J_1,\ldots,I_g,J_g$. Then $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $Isom^+\left({\Bbb H}^2\right)$ and $\Gamma\backslash{\Bbb H}^2$ is a hyperbolic surface diffeomorphic to ${\Bbb H}^2$.

Here is an illustration for genus 2 surface glued from an octagon in hyperbolic plane
(image taken from [here](http://topologygeometry.blogspot.com/2010/06/notes-from-062310.html)):

[image]